# Game Breaking Glitch in Binding of Isaac: Rebirth steam version. (Disk Read error)

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Okay, so I don't remember much about this because I asked on the Steam fourms and I forgot about it a bit. But here is what is happening:

I was playing The Binding of Isaac, I quit for a bit after a successful azazel run, and I assume while the game was dormant, an update came out.
Later after that I tried to play, but I got a corrupt save error. 
I tried to verify game cache. I forgot the result. But it was a failure. Obviously.
I uninstalled, and reinstalled, fiddled and bam-boozed, slammed my chair and put my hands into my face, after maybe 10 mins of trying to work on it, it became a disk read error.
If I uninstall and reinstall it just pauses the download when it reaches 100. Thus for I can't verify game cache.

Answer (score 1):

For one, SOLVED!!!!!!!!!

And two, heres how for anyone else who gets shrekt by the gltich

If you uninstall the game, the .exe is still here, just go to Steam>steamapps>common.
Delete local game content for BoI: Rebirth through steam, delete the .exe then reinstall. Its that easy!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with steam. To notify them of the problem go to the link below and see if you can find a similar problem if not, create a steam support account (it's stupid, a separate account just for support) and submit the problem

https://support.steampowered.com/